# Cut off text that cut the y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a horizontal bar chart. I want the label in the bar, but if it crosses the y-axis it needs to be clipped.

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ['Book 1', 'Book 2', 'Book 3']
values = [20, 35, 5]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

y_pos = range(len(labels))
ax.barh(y_pos, values, align='center', color='blue')
for i, v in enumerate(values):
    ax.text(v, i, "TESTSTETSTSTS", color='grey', va='center', ha='right')

ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.set_xlabel('Number')
ax.set_title('Number of sold books')

plt.show()
```

Wrong result:

[image]

Right result:

[image]

Comment: `ax.text(..., clip_on=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fixed code.

CODE

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ['Book 1', 'Book 2', 'Book 3']
values = [20, 35, 5]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

y_pos = range(len(labels))
ax.barh(y_pos, values, align='center', color='blue')
for i, v in enumerate(values):
    ax.text(v, i, "TESTSTETSTSTS", color='grey', va='center', ha='right', clip_on=True) #HERE IS THE FIX

ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.set_xlabel('Number')
ax.set_title('Number of sold books')

plt.show()
```

[evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWlKR.png)